# What are init, start, render_value in Odoo 8 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to JavaScript and Odoo. Whenever I open the JavaScript files of the base modules, I see `init`, `start`, `sometimes`, `render_value`. What are these things for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Jeremy Gillbert,

You can reffered this document [Click here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/javascript.html)

**Start** = > Basically the Start of an application JavaScript, where the code begins to be executed, is when is called the method window.OnLoad, after the page, is fully loaded, and automatically call it method, there exist others way to call code from the page.

**Init** = > init is just shorthand for the initiate. Typically it is used to create a "new Object()" with return the same.

**render_value** => render_value means,To grab an input value with javascript and render it into a div or particular element.

Thanks

Comment: I have read the documentation but I still don't clearly understand what they are. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Start = > Basically the Start of an application JavaScript, where the code begins to be executed, is when is called the method window.OnLoad, after the page is fully loaded, and automatically call it method, there exists others way to call code from the page.

Comment: Init = > init is just shorthand for the initiate. Typically it is used to create a "new Object()" with return the same.

Comment: render_value => render_value means,To grab an input value with javascript and render it into a div or particular element.

Comment: Thanks, Dipen Shah. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @DipenShah could you edit the answer and copy your comments into it? It's not good to reference/link an external documentation as the only thing in an answer, because links don't exist forever.